# Devexpress DataGrid or PivotGrid Header and Footer when exporting to Excel

Tags: winforms, excel, datagrid, devexpress, export

I am using the Devexpress DataGrid and PivotGrid controls. I need to implement methods that will export the reports to Excel.

The built in methods: ExportToXls allow me to export to excel, however I cannot find a way to include header and footer information to the excel file. Is there a way I can do this? Can someone direct me to some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such functionality using DevExpress `PrintableComponentLink`

This link has an example: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument3427

The idea is to add header and footer text (for example) to your datagrid.

Once you do that you can do: `yourPrintableComponentLink.ExportToXls(yourStream);`